# Change Product type From physical Configurable/Simple to Virtual after adding it to basket

Tags: magento2, product

Is it possible that we can change product type in quote. 
We dont want to change product type in database but only for specific quote. When user add any configurable product to cart then based on some conditions (we will define them in event) we will flip product type from configurable physical to virtual.

Comment: I think it can be done, as far as i remember quote and quote_item have is_virtual field in case quote has virtual products. Try to set this field as true in both tables.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to create Observer to update product type.**
**If you have created module then** 
Mageseller/UpdateProduct/etc/event.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
        <observer name="custom_update_product_type" instance="Mageseller\UpdateProduct\Observer\UpdateProductType" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**Now create below file** Mageseller/UpdateProduct/Observer/UpdateProductType.php **in Observer folder.**

```
<?php
    namespace Mageseller\UpdateProduct\Observer;

    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

    class UpdateProductType implements ObserverInterface
    {
        public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
            $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');         
            $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );
            $productType = 'virtual'; //set your price here
            // condition starts
            $item->setProductType($productType);
            $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
            // condition ends
        }

    }
```